# Ubuntu 16.04 can't mount external HDD with two partitions (Win and Linux)

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have an external HDD that has a Windows and a Ubuntu partitions. I can't mount it on Ubuntu 16.04. 
The outputs of `ls /dev/ | grep sd` before and after connecting the HDD differ by the following line:

```
sdb
```

I tried:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt
```

but I got the following

```
mount: no medium found on /dev/sdb
```

This is the output of `sudo lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 238.5G  0 disk 
├─sda4   8:4    0     1G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   104G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0 125.6G  0 part 
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda6   8:6    0   7.9G  0 part [SWAP]
```

Is there a way to mount both partitions?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You mount partitions, not devices. E.g. `mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt`. If you need both partitinons, mount them one by one ;-) to different mount points.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/939663/edit) your question with the output of `sudo lsblk`. Also, don't forget to add @Raphael at the start of your comment if you are addressing to me. Otherwise, I might miss your reply.

Comment: @Pilot6 I already tried that, and I got `mount: no medium found on /dev/sdb`

Comment: Do you see the difference between `sdb` and `sdb1`?

Comment: There's no sdb in the output of `sudo lsblk`. What are you trying to mount?

Comment: @Pilot6 I don't understand what you mean

Comment: I mean that you cant mount a disk, you can mount a partition. The thing I can't understand is where do you see `sdb`? You probably gave output of `lsblk` without the disk.

Comment: @Raphael I have a HDD that I extracted from an old PC and I would like to use as an external drive. It has two partitions, a Win and a Ubuntu one. When I plug it in my Ubuntu laptop, it doesn't automatically open. The only difference that I can see is that, when I do `ls /dev/ | grep sd` I get an extra line with `sdb` when the HDD is plugged in

Comment: So plugin the disk and give the output of `lsblk`.

Comment: @Pilot6 the output of `lsblk` with the device plugged in is already in my question